# Is it possible to grant INJECT_EVENTS permission to an app for dev/testing purposes

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm working on an app that gets installed into system/app (the apk gets delivered to phone manufacturers who include into the system image).

I want to perform some proof of concept experiments that requires adding the INJECT_EVENTS permission to the app. AFAIK, in order for an app to be granted this permission a) it needs to be a system app and b) it needs to be signed with the system certificate.

a) is no problem as that is where the app will go eventually, and I'm also working with a rooted device.

However I don't have the system certificate for b).

In order to develop and test the app before it gets delivered to the phone manufacturers, is there a way I can grant this permission to the app?

adb shell pm grant "app package" android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS results in this:

```
Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS is not a changeable permission type
```

Comment: Rooted device perhaps. If not, use a custom ROM for which you do have the system certificate.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The adb shell is not a SU user. use the RunTime to inject shell commands as SU. Use any tool to grant you SU privileges, then execute your command

```
Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su pm grant 'app package' android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS");
suProcess.waitFor();
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there is a way of granting the permission that isn't done at runtime?

Comment: it depends mostly on how the ROM is granting SU privileges... since most android users that become root do NOT want to grant programs any privilege, I cant really tell... in my case, I use an app that grants privileges, and this app has an "always allow X program SU privileges", once set,  whenever privileges are requested, they are always granted.... still, it is granted at runtime... If you "need" to be sure you wont get requested, you have to find the SU shell binary and grant "yourapp-user", system wide privileges (but I dont know details on how to do that)

Comment: doesn't work. seems like INJECT_EVENTS is not grantable.

Comment: @mysh It does work, however, it does not work, in systems without "grant SU" binaries (Stock Versions wont have it). You need to either install a Super/Switch User application, or have a rooted device. INJECT_EVENTS, like any other permission can be tempered with, with the appropriate application

Comment: For me it doesn't work. "Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS is not a changeable permission type". This on Lollipop 5.1, at least.

Comment: @DADi590 yes, read the question, read the answer and then read the previous comments. `INJECT_EVENTS` is a System level permission, and cannot be granted. I used rooted devices, that allow me to do whatever on the System, such as using shell to grant permissions.

Comment: @Bonatti My bad. Should have mentioned also that I installed the app as a System app. I thought your method could override the "signature" protection level (https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/6109ea3b1607a1f14290f3e2fea6cc0da957d20f/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml#L3033). No idea if it's because of that. But it didn't work with me even as System app. Also, I have a rooted phone, btw. Gives that error.

Comment: @DADi590 What root tool are you using? ChainFire? Magisk? Other? When you programmatically request the access, what does your shell reply?

Comment: @Bonatti I'm using Magisk and I sent the command through ADB from Android Studio. From the app, I have this reading the output and printing it (prints null, and on ADB throws that error), and gives an error on waitFor() which is number 1, if this helps (sorry if it's not what you meant, I'm kind of a begginer on Android yet).
PS: I also have Shell and my app with Root permissions.

Comment: @DADi590 Thats what I, and the other comments are saying. The ADB shell user is different from your application user (application ID wise). Thus, having ADB shell granted root, does nothing to your application. You need to start a process yourself, with your application (the answer is an example), and then issue the commands through the input/output of the` Process`.  Then, you need a binary that is able to grant non-grantable permissions, and execute it. OR a binary that does what you intend to.

Comment: not working this issue in android 13
need to root device firstly

Comment: @kishanverma Please, read the answer, where its written about the super user (root). There is no available root user on non-rooted devices.

Answer (score -2):

Go to Developer options and on usb debugging(Security setting)...INJECT_EVENTS error will be solved